# How can I use my date feature on my algorithm?

Tags: python, datetime, dataframe, machine-learning, scikit-learn

```
X = df1.iloc[:, 1:].values
y = df1.iloc[:, 0].values

from sklearn.cross_validation import train_test_split
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.25,     random_state=0) 

from sklearn.neighbors import KNeighborsClassifier
knn = KNeighborsClassifier(n_neighbors=3, metric='minkowski', p=2)
knn.fit(X_train, y_train)

ValueError: could not convert string to float: '2/1/2011'
```

I'm planning on making a betting model using these features.
FTR = full time result : (H)ome, (D)raw, (A)way
odds_H = odds of home team

- [df with onehotencoding](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c8gxW.png)
- [original df](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iPVrP.png)

Comment: what are the attributes

Comment: Can you get your `df` in text format instead of a `PNG` so that others can use that data to simulate your problem? You can simply copy/paste data and tag it as either code or Blockquote.

Answer (score 0):

In ML, there are quite a few things you can do if you have dates as a feature. Some examples of transformations that have been useful in the past:

- Day number, month number, year number, quarter number
- Week day
- Season (e.g spring=0, summer=1 ...)
- year_day number (1-jan = 0, 31-dec = 364)
- Number of days since/before some event (in your example this could be number of days since the previous match)
- And many more...

There are a few caveats with some of them, but in general it should be easy to go from a `datetime` object to each of these representations (as integers). And depending on your particular dataset, some of them may be really useful.